# Challenges with Transforming Postgresql into Redshift (Filter Where)

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I noticed something when transforming into the redshift dialect from postgresql, when using filter where, but can't quite explain why the 2 queries yield different results. I hope someone can explain.

Postgresql:

```
select date_trunc('week', date)::DATE as "Week", 
date_trunc('year', date)::DATE as "Year",
country, 
region, 
count(distinct o.id) filter (where status='delivered') as "Delivered",
count(distinct o.id) filter (where status='packaged') as "Packaged"
from country as c
left join orders as o on c.order_id=o.id and date_trunc('week', o.date)::DATE=date_trunc('week', c.date)::DATE and date_trunc('year', o.date)::DATE=date_trunc('year', c.date)::DATE
where country='IT'
and product='CAT'
group by 1,2
order by 1
```

With this query I can see how many orders were delivered and packaged for that year and week for country IT, product CAT

Transforming to Redshift (can't use filter where - substituting with case when)

```
select extract(week from date) as "Week", 
extract(year from date) as "Year", 
country, 
region, 
case when status='delivered' then count(distinct o.id) as "Delivered",
case when status='packaged' then count(distinct o.id) as "Packaged"
from country as c
left join orders as o on c.order_id=o.id and extract(week from o.date)=extract(week from c.date) and extract(year from o.date)=extract(year from c.date)
where country='IT'
and product='CAT'
group by 1,2, status
order by 1
```

so a couple of changes here:

1. date_trunc to extract
2. filter (where ..) to case when
3. add status to group by (otherwise I get an error)

But the major issue is that I am not getting the same output, instead I have several rows for the same weeks and values are skipping rows. (so it is not just duplicated rows, I can easy get rid of by using distinct)

Answer (score 0):

You have the `case` in the wrong place.  The equivalent logic is:

```
select date_trunc('week', date)::DATE as Week, 
       date_trunc('year', date)::DATE as Year,
       country, region, 
       count(distinct case when status = 'delivered' then o.id end) as Delivered,
       count(distinct case when status = 'packaged' then o.id end) as Packaged
from country c left join
     orders o
     on c.order_id = o.id and
        date_trunc('week', o.date)::DATE = date_trunc('week', c.date)::DATE and
        date_trunc('year', o.date)::DATE = date_trunc('year', c.date)::DATE
where country = 'IT' and product = 'CAT'
group by 1, 2
order by 1;
```